# Why won't daskeyboard work with kvms?

Tags: keyboard, kvm-switch

What prevents das keyboard from working with kvms? (info from [www.daskeyboard.com](http://www.daskeyboard.com))  Why would a keyboard not be compatible with a kvm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be the integrated USB hub.

Because the KVM has to pass the keyboard commands through to the machine, most are probably not designed to work in USB daisy-chaining configurations. Some KVM's even convert the USB interface to the old PS2 interface.